# what is difference between $('.classname') and $.find('.classname')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Sometimes `$('.classname')` and `$.find('.classname')` gives different result. Wondering what is the difference between both.

Comment: Did you mean `$(some selector).find('.classname')` instead of `$.find('.classname')`? Because I am not aware of the existence of a static `$.find` function in jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I see. Could you point me to the documentation of this function as I cannot seem to find it?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov There is no documentation this is an internal method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.classname')
```

will search the DOM for elements with class `classname` and

```
$.find('.classname')
```

will <s>give you error</s> do nothing, [**why**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> .find( selector )
>
> selectorA string containing a selector expression to match elements
> against. version added: 1.6.
>
> .find( jQuery object )
> jQuery objectA jQuery object to match elements against. version added:
> 1.6
>
> .find( element )
> elementAn element to match elements against.

Comment: @rituparnakashyap right will do nothing would be more appropriate

Comment: See the latest code for `jQuery.find` NOT `jQuery.fn.find`. http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.find . it's a method used by jQuery internally.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you,

but you can see the source-code for [$.find](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.find) and for [$.fn.find](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.find)

**`$.find`**:

It's a method used by jQuery itself and not recomented to use as query selector.

**`$.fn.find`**:

Refers to `$.find` in the core framework: (where `this` is a jQuery Object)

```
var ret = this.pushStack("", "find", selector),
    length, n, r;

for (i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
    length = ret.length;
    jQuery.find(selector, this[i], ret);

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.classname')` will return a list of all of the elements with that classname in the document so they can be iterated with `.each()`.

`$.find('.classname')` searches the dom tree and returns occurances of the class. But you would have to supply a parent element, eg:

`$(document).find('.classname')`